# How to get a mobile bootstrap navigation to remain on top of the screen

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navigation

I have recently deployed a website online using bootstrap as the front-end framework. I included the jQuery button to have the menu dropdown on clicking on it. During tests using my Chrome browser emulator, the navigation seems to work well, with it dropping down over the rest of the website content. However, on checking the same site using my iPhone 4s, the nav shows briefly for a split second and then disappears. I have fought tooth and nail with the CSS, but I can't seem to crack it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The web address is [www.dof.com.ng](http://dof.com.ng)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You approach this using `position:fixed` rather than relative. Your menu as it stands would take a bit of reworking to accommodate that because your content would shift up and would need extra margins.

Comment: @Aibrean I did not add a position: fixed anywhere within the navigation

Comment: Yea, that's why it's not at the top.

Comment: Hi @Aibrean I have tried this and it still doesn't work

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: @Aibrean clicking on the menu button on the website on the iPhone does not do anything. No menu shows up... there is no visual change on the website whatsoever

Comment: But it stays at the top...that means you need to adjust the content so nothing is overlapping into the menu.

Comment: when you view the site on mobile, does it show a menu when you click on the menu button? It does not do so on any of the mobile devices I have tested (android, iOS and Windows Phone)

Comment: It does with the Chrome emulator.

Comment: @Aibrean yeah it works with the emulator, but it does not work on the actual device.. which is quite weird

Comment: If you don't have it fixed on the live site there is no way for me to test it on my phone.

Comment: hi @Aibrean i have changed the position to fixed on the live site now. The drop down menu still does not show. However, I have noticed that you can click on the links within the nav even though you can not see them. I have changed the z-index to 100, but still no luck :(